# Shortcut to add a zoom meeting in Outlook web (OWA) calendar

Tags: calendar, outlook-web-access

I use outlook.com (also called OWA) for email and calendar.

The end goal is via shortcuts, click on the option to add a zoom meeting

[image]

Given that I've not found any shortcut (which would have been the better answer), I am trying to create some automation via auto hot key but to do so, I need to find out some shortcuts and I've failed at this too.

What I want to do is either

1. Have the first item, `Scheduling Assistant` 'highlighted' so I can tab along via keystroke automation OR
2. A direct shortcut to the ellipse (the 3 dots) in order to automate keystrokes to navigate to the more options pane.

Is this possible?